# WP Email Capture - Switch language

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I use WP Email Capture on a project. I saw this plugin come with many translations, including the one I need. The thing is : the plugin stays in english, I just don't know how to switch language to french.

I saw there is a `/wp-email-capture/languages/WPEC-fr_FR.po`, but I don't know how to activate it, or simply to use it...

By the way, in my wp-config.php:

```
 define('WPLANG', 'fr_FR');
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing does appear to work for me — see:

[image]

*However*, the French translation was done on an old version, and I added a lot more features since then (such as a right hand column). So it's just a partial translation for now.

I would update it, but I only speak rudimentary French! :)

Comment: Thank you, only the placeholders of input text and mail were in English actually... If you need help with FR translation, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Always :) - drop me an email about it through wpemailcapture.com :)